# Bazel - Pybind - Pytorch - Undefined Symbol

Tags: python, pytorch, bazel, pybind11, libtorch

Attempting to write a toy example with Bazel, Pybind, Pytorch/Libtorch fails with the following error on import of the custom library

```
import libTest
undefined symbol: _ZN3c1019UndefinedTensorImpl10_singletonE
```

The Bazel WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
    name = "pytorch_cpu",
    build_file = "//tools:pytorch_cpu.BUILD",
    sha256 = "6b99edc046f37ad37a3b04dc86663895f10c362af09fdd10884f30360d0ba023",
    urls = [
        "https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-1.9.0%2Bcpu.zip"
    ],
)
```

The Bazel Build file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_library(
    name = "pytorch_cpu",
    includes = ["libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include", "libtorch/include"],
    hdrs = glob([
      "libtorch/include/**"
    ]),
    srcs = glob([
      "libtorch/lib/*",
    ]),
)
```

And the toy example in Pybind

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/pytypes.h>


#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <torch/csrc/utils/pybind.h>


namespace py = pybind11;

torch::Tensor myUsefulMethod() 
{
  return torch::zeros({62,1});
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(libTest, m) {

  m.def("myUsefulMethod", &myUsefulMethod, "myUsefulMethod");

  #ifdef VERSION_INFO
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
  #else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
  #endif
}

#endif
```

built as

```
cc_library(
    name = "Test",
    srcs = ["Test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@pybind11",
        "@pytorch_cpu"
    ],
)
```

What might be the issue here? This setup seems to work fine in Cmake, but gives the undefined tensor impl error in my bazel setup. Just to note, Libtorch 1.9 binaries were pulled from that above link and pytorch 1.9 installed in it's own pyenv using the default pip install instructions. But they are certainly the same version

Comment: Hi. Have you checked this resource. It provides 2 solutions: Either adjusting torchvision version by reinstalling or installing from source and import torch before libtest package. https://github.com/jwyang/faster-rcnn.pytorch/issues/612

Comment: is it really needed to install from source? I did try to import torch first, but same issue

Comment: I am able to get a cpp binary to link to a library containing torchlib deps, but somehow it doesnt workj with python